# Appium unlock does not work on some devices [Android]

Tags: java, android, appium, unlock

I have an issue with appium unlock on android. It works on 50% of devices. It tries to unlock but unsuccessfully.

My capabilities:

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability(APP, APP_PATH_LOCAL); //TODO LOCAL
//        capabilities.setCapability(APP, APP_PATH_REMOTE); //TODO REMOTE
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, F_APP_PACKAGE);
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, F_APP_ACTIVITY);
        capabilities.setCapability(DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
        capabilities.setCapability(UDID, id);
        capabilities.setCapability(NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 20);
        capabilities.setCapability(PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
        androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(LOCAL), capabilities); //TODO LOCAL
//          androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(REMOTE), capabilities); //TODO REMOTE
```

TestNG logs:

o`rg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Screen did not unlock successfully, retrying (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information`)

Appium logs:

```
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","wait-for-device"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","echo","ping"]
[debug] [Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","install","/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/io.appium.settings/bin/settings_apk-debug.apk"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","install","/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-unlock/bin/unlock_apk-debug.apk"]
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.release"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[AndroidDriver] Unlocking screen
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.sdk"]
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Screen is locked, trying to unlock
[debug] [ADB] Device API level: 21
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","am","start","-n","io.appium.unlock/.Unlock","-S","-a","android.intent.action.MAIN","-c","android.intent.category.LAUNCHER","-f","0x10200000"]
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /home/igor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","4d009d021274404b","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[AndroidDriver] Cannot shut down Android driver; it has already shut down
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Screen did not unlock successfully, retrying
    at Object.callee$1$0$ (lib/android-helpers.js:348:13)
    at tryCatch (/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/home/igor/Node/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 43019 ms - 181
```

I tried to unlock device programatically from adb using this method:

```
public void unlockDevice() throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 26");
    }
```

But it do nothing

Maybe its possible to push power button using androidDriver before setting up capabilities?
androidDriver.pressKeyCode(26);
Or possible to run adb command from code using Java?
Or something else to unlock device?

Comment: You should give it a look: There is an issue at https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/issues/146 which involving your issue. You could try to update new release of [appium-android-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-android-driver).

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the activity:

```
adb shell am start -n io.appium.unlock/.Unlock
```

Comment: Appium's unlock fixed on Appium 1.5.3.
But thanks for answer